# ¿Cómo deshabilitar un campo para que no se pueda modificar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-forms

Estoy haciendo un fórmulario en el que hay un campo de aceptar politicas que al marcarlo la primera vez no se debe modificar pero cuando está marcado y modifican otro campo vuelve a False de nuevo.

### Formulario

```
class PerfilForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Perfil
        fields = ['tel','tel_fijo','entrg_pais','entrg_dep','entrg_ciudad','entrg_direccion',
                    'entrg_cp','rmt_pais','rmt_dep','rmt_direccion','rmt_ciudad','rmt_cp',
                    'num_cc','avatar','propietario_cc','banco','tipo_cc','tipo_ident','cedula_o_nit',
                    'descp_armario','acepta_politicas']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PerfilForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance.pk and self.instance.acepta_politicas:
            self.fields['acepta_politicas'].widget.attrs.update({'disabled': True})
```

Comment: Quizás si el valor se actualiza en tus modelos puede ser por algo que tengas definido por defecto que haga que cambie, lo que sucede al ser un campo den `disabled` es que cuando haces la petición de vuelta al servidor ese campo no se envía, y supondré que al no leerlo, automáticamente se evalúa `False`. Lo que puedes hacer es no solo validar en el front que es fácil de engañar si no también hacerlo en el backend. Para ello crea otro formulario pero en la metaclase en los `fields` no agregues el campo `acepta_politicas` de esta forma no lo evaluará

Comment: Tienes razón, tenia en el modelo un default False y estaba sobreescribiendo eso sin querer...